# Convert binary data variable to the list of bytes

Tags: tcl

I have binary data variable that I read from file `set data [read $fp 5]`. Let's say it is: `0102030405` in hex representation.

How can I convert it to the list of bytes like this:
`{0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05}`?

I have a function that requires binary data as a list. I suppose `binary scan` is what I need, but can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; `binary scan` is the tool you need. You probably want to do this:

```
binary scan $data "cu*" byteValues
```

That produces, in `byteValues`, the list of unsigned byte values. (The `b` conversion produces bit strings, which isn't what you want.) For example:

```
% binary scan Abc "cu*" theValues
1
% puts $theValues
65 98 99
```

If you are dealing with an old version of Tcl, you'll need `c*` instead of `cu*` and then the top bit of each byte is the sign bit. The result is *technically correct* but not something I've ever found very useful.

Comment: The result of `binary scan` is always the number of fields filled. In this case, that's always going to be 1 and so isn't very interesting.